# real time scripting C# REPL - CLI or VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there any REPL for `C#/.NET 4.5` that can work either in **VisualStudio 2013 express** or **cli**.

I tried:

1. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/295fa0f6-37d1-49a3-b51d-ea4741905dc2 -not working with vs 2013
2. MS Roslyn - also not working with 2013
3. vs gallery, SO questions etc without luck

Comment: I've had good luck with the Immediate Window in the debugger. Also Mono has a C# REPL.

Comment: @AustinMullins Immediate window is working in the context of the breakpoint, and only if it stops at some breakpoint, right? Checking mono as well, thanks.

Comment: Downvote and voting to close as opinionated comes in handy, really..

Comment: Yes. It's a REPL with the breakpoint's context, which makes it my favorite.

Comment: @AustinMullins great, already trying it out, think it will be just what I needed. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Well, the problem is that questions asking for tool recommendations are usually off-topic. There is a software recommendations SE site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best tools for Visual Studio debugging are included right within the IDE, even in the Express version. In this case, the tool of choice is the Immediate Window, which is usually docked with the Output window in the lower section of the IDE.

To use it, you'll need to build your project in the Debug configuration and set a breakpoint at a useful point in the code. For example, I might debug a class like this:

```
namespace MyThings
{
  public class Thing
  {
    private string thingName = "default name";
    public string ThingName
    {
      get { return thingName; }
      private set { thingName = value; }
    }

    public Thing(string name)
    {
      thingName = name;
    }

    public SayThing()
    {
      string thingsToSay = thingName + " and things.";  // Set breakpoint here
      Console.WriteLine("I have some {0}", thingsToSay);
    }
  }

  public static class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
       var thing = new Thing("My thing");
       thing.SayThing();
    }
  }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at the indicated line and run this with the Visual Studio debugger, I should gain access to the Immediate Window at a point where the following inputs will work:

```
this
    {MyThings.Thing ...}
       ThingName: "My thing"
       thingName: "My thing"

thingsToSay
    My thing and things.
```

At this point you can step through the method using the toolbar buttons or hitting `F10` or `F11` to step over or step into instructions as desired. The immediate window really gives you a lot of insight into what's going on and how to get around problems. You can even create new variables in your present scope:

```
var otherThingToTry = thingName + " another string to concatenate, I guess?";
otherThingToTry
  "My thing another string to concatenate, I guess?"
```

It's hugely helpful, even if my examples aren't.